# How do I make my camera follow the curve smoothly, without bumps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, bezier-curves

The camera follows a path inside the tunnel, but after each turn, kind of snaps back or bumps, like a recoil of sorts. I reduced the size of the turns, but it still happens. I put on a damped track which seems to help, but the only reason it looks kind of decent is because the camera is set to 15mm. The other issue is that when it's rendered, the tunnel lights keep on shifting hues, even though I have the same point light duplicated within. Here's the file. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright, reinstated. You should not edited into your previous question into something completely different, otherwise answers won't make sense anymore. If you have a different question make a new post. You should also only ask one question per post, make as many as necessary

Comment: Got it, thank you, I understand now

Comment: Convert your curve type from *Bezier* into *Path*

Comment: I can't find where that is, somewhere in edit mode?

Comment: Either add a new curve from `Shift+A`> *Curve* > *Path* or in *Edit Mode* convert your curve to *NURBS* with `Shift+T` or from *3D View Menu > Curve > Set Spline Type*

Comment: @Duarte, what does it change to convert to nurbs? The movement looks normal on my computer, the bumps could happen because of your curve resolution but it's already 100 for Preview (maybe you need to increase the Render U though)...

Comment: @moonboots bezier curves often have inherent precision issues with animations, its not even Blender specific, 3Ds Max used to suffer the same. Changing to other math models used to mitigate this. Not sure if this is the case, though this was the specific purpose of *Path* curve types

Comment: ok I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: Once I convert the bezier into a nurbs path it loses shape, because all the hook modifiers that I used with empties stop applying. So now it's just a straight line.